# How to make 'for' loop more efficiency and rapid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, spacy, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to loop in a list of word to extract sentences (string) which contains specific word.

I come up with this little code :

```
import spacy.attrs
import spacy
from spacy.lang.fr import French
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex

nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_md")
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
import itertools

sentences_list = ['je suis', 'je', 'tu as mal','sois au repos','laisse moi','ta tête','tu es là', 'tu es laid']
sentences_with_word []
for elt in sentences_list:
      doc = nlp(elt)
      #print(doc)
      for tok in doc:
        #print(tok.text, "-->", tok.lemma_, "-->", tok.dep_, "-->", tok.pos_)
        if tok.lemma_ in lexique :
          if doc not in sentences_with_word:
            sentences_with_word.append(doc)
```

I have more than 300 000k elt and this took forever to run How can I make it more efficiently to reduce time.

```
sentences_other =[]
d_sent = {}
for sent in sentences_list:
      mytokens = nlp(sent)
      mytokens2 = [word.lemma_.lower().strip() for word in mytokens if word.pos_ != "SPACE"]
      d_sent[sent] = " ".join(mytokens2)

    #print(d_sent)

    for k, v in d_sent.items():
      for w in motif : 
        #print(word)
        if w in v:
          #print(w)
          if k not in sentences_other:
            sentences_other.append(k)
```

Both code run but take too long  (it laready more than one hour) since the numbers of elt are huge.  Do you you know how can I make it more efficiently to reduce time ?

I used Spacy library.

Comment: Note that comprehensions do not provide significant performance benefits, and may in fact be slower than ``for`` statements.

Comment: the actual line codes already took more than 1 one hour to search in 300 000k

Comment: If you don't need to keep the order of elements, make `sentences_with_word` a set (or a `Counter`) instead of a list. Lookup (`if doc not in sentences_with_word`) will be `O(1)` vs `O(n)`. Same goes for `sentences_other`.